# Center of the adjoint group of a semisimple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $K$ be a compact semisimple Lie group. The adjoint group $K'$ associated to $K$ is defined as the image of $K$ under the adjoint representation Ad:$K\to GL(\mathfrak{k})$.

I think that $K'\cong K/Z(K)$. I am trying to show that the center of $K'$ is trivial but I don't have any idea how to prove this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a simpler proof as follows:
Let $[a]\in Z(K')$, then it follows that for any $b\in K$ we have
$$
a^{-1}b^{-1}ab\in Z(K).
$$
Now we consider the continuous function $\phi_a:K\to K$ defined by
$$
\phi_a(b)=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab.
$$
Then $\phi_a$ maps $K$ into $Z(K)$. However, since $K$ is semisimple, the center of $\mathfrak{k}$ (the Lie algebra of K) is trivial. Therefore, $Z(K)$ is discrete and it follows that $\phi_a$ is a constant function and in particular equals identity. Therefore, $a\in Z(K)$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the following result can be found in the literature, e.g. [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiH8KCy4_7qAhWGyqQKHeOvC2cQFjAHegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nd.edu%2F%7Ewgd%2FDvi%2FElementary.Lie.Groups.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2wk2HGxDvmddBswdALWQYK), Propostion $7.2$, with a proof on page $14$:

**Theorem:** Suppose that $G$ is a connected compact Lie group and that $C$ is the center of $G$. Then the center of $G/C$ is trivial.

*Proof:* Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$. Then $T$ contains $C$ and $T/C$ is a torus. The diffeomorphism
$$
(G/C)/(T/C) ≃ G/T
$$
shows that $\chi((G/C)/(T/C))$ is nonzero and thus that $T/C$ is a maximal torus for $G/C$. Suppose that $x$ is a non-identity element of $G/C$ and that $\tilde{x}\in G$ is an element which projects to $x$. Since $\tilde{x}\not\in C$, there is a maximal torus $T′$ for $G$ which does not
contain $\tilde{x}$. Then $T′/C$ is a maximal torus for $G/C$ which does not contain $x$, and so $x$ does not belong to the center of $G/C$. Hence this center is trivial.